# Moving elasticsearch from heroku to dokku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, elasticsearch, digital-ocean

So i had been using searchkick lovely on heroku

However i'm moving to digital ocean and using dokku

How would i go about making elasticsearch work with this? I was trying to follow tutorials but it hasn't worked (i've reverted back to an old snapshot)

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

As I commented on the other issue, dokku provides official plugins for most major datastores. The elasticsearch plugin is [available here](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-elasticsearch).